# Creating a volatile table with an automatically incremented field and referential integrity constraints

Tags: sql, teradata, volatile, create-table

As a junior SQA, I don't have write/read access to tables in Teradata - only read access for views. I recently discovered volatile tables, and they have made my life so much easier. While they are extremely helpful, I'm wondering if it's possible to create a volatile table with an auto incremented primary key (or index), and also referential integrity constraints?

Here is the SQL I've been to working with.

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE Article (
    user_id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
    (
        START WITH 1
        INCREMENT BY 20
        MAXVALUE 2147483647
    )
    ,user_url varchar(1000) NOT NULL
    ,user_title varchar(200)
    --,PRIMARY KEY (art_id)
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

The error message I'm getting with this code:

```
CREATE TABLE Failed. 5784: Illegal usage of Identity Column user_id
```

As you can see, I'm trying to create an auto incremented field, but haven't yet tried implementing any referential integrity constraints.

So to sum it up, my questions would be:

```
1. Can a field of a volatile table be automatically incremented and, if
   possible, how is this accomplished?
2. Can referential integrity constraints be included in creating a volatile 
   table and, if possible, how is this accomplished?
```

If anyone could shed some light on my questions, I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: You have the correct syntaxt for automatically incremented field (identity), why do you think it is not working?

Comment: I'm not sure, that's why I turned to Stack Overflow :)

The error message I'm getting is: "Illegal usage of Identity Column user_id"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this: 
http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/General_Reference/B035_1096_111A/Database.26.1905.html

> Illegal usage of Identity Column user_id: An identity column is defined in a temporary or volatile table. It may
>   only be defined in a permanent table.

However, there are other ways to generate surrogate keys in a volatile table of Teradata, but only when inserting data in your table, and not when it is created:
http://forums.teradata.com/forum/database/generate-surrogatekey-with-a-huge-table

In general:

1. You can have 1000 volatile tables in an active session.
2. CHECK and REFERENTIAL constraints are not allowed.
3. DEFAULT clause not allowed.

Comment: Thanks for the response and providing links, they really help.

Comment: you are welcome, I added the answer to your second question